# How to render invisible chars in a text area?

Tags: fonts, html, css, utf-8, input

Assuming this is not a text renderer limitation, and that a font can opt to show those chars, I would like to have things like `u2028` (LS - Line Separator) and `u2029` (PS - Paragraph Separator) rendered in some way. Right now they simply appear as nothing, not even a space in some cases.

Maybe there is a font I can use (ideally one that has a license I can also distribute as a webfont) where those invisible chars will become visible?

Maybe some CSS property? Anything?